# Calculate total amount of rows for specific date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this working.

```
 $queryPR = "SELECT * FROM `raport` WHERE DATE(`timestamp`) = CURDATE() AND (lokacioni = 'PR')";
```

I need the total amount of rows calculated for specific date.

I need also to the `SUM('pagesat')` somehow but I have no idea how.

Find the whole code below.

*I am trying to build something simple to show the income and outcome for 3 locations that we have.*

```
<table class="responsive-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Vetura</th>
                <th>Targa</th>
                <th>Dite</th>
                <th>Pagesa</th>
                <th>Cmimi Ditore</th>
                <th>Vazhdim</th>
                <th>Te Tjera</th>
                <th>Shpenzime</th>
                <th>Komente</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
           <?php

                $query = "SELECT * FROM `raport` WHERE DATE(`timestamp`) = CURDATE() AND (lokacioni = 'FR')";

                $stmt = $DBcon->prepare( $query );
                $stmt->execute();

            while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['vetura']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['targa']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['dite']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['pagesa']; ?>€</td>
                <td><?php echo $row['cmimiditore']; ?>€</td>
                <td><?php echo $row['vazhdim']; ?>€</td>
                <td><?php echo $row['tetjera']; ?>€</td>
                <td><?php echo $row['shpenzime']; ?>€</td>
                <td><?php echo $row['koment']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                $pagesa = $row['pagesa'];
                $tetjera = $row['tetjera'];
                $vazhdime = $row['vazhdim'];
                $shpenzime = $row['shpenzime'];
            }?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <?php


        $totali = ($pagesa + $vazhdime + $tetjera);
        $gtotal = ($totali - $shpenzime);



    ?>
    <div class="card grey">
        <hgroup class="totalDitorRaport">
            <h2>Total</h2>
            <h1><?php echo $gtotal; ?>€</h1>
        </hgroup>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

get the sum of the row `pagesa` in the loop

```
$queryPR = "SELECT * FROM `raport` WHERE DATE(`timestamp`) = CURDATE() AND (lokacioni = 'PR')";

$stmt = $DBcon->prepare( $query );
                $stmt->execute();

   $sum = 0;
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

 $sum += $row['pagesa'];

 }
echo $sum;
```

Comment: This works somehow thank you :)
But the problem now its that its only calculating one row not all entries for today.

Comment: The same brother, it will calculate only one row.

Comment: see the updated answer i have changed the query also